# Unable to infer lifetime for borrow expression when using a trait with an explicit lifetime

Tags: rust, lifetime

```
use std::io::BufReader;
struct Foo {
    buf: [u8, ..10]
}

trait Bar<'a> {
    fn test(&self, arg: BufReader<'a>) {}
}

impl<'a, T: Bar<'a>> Foo {
    fn bar(&'a mut self, t: T) {
        t.test(BufReader::new(&self.buf));
        let b = &mut self.buf;
    }

    fn baz(&self, t: T) {
        t.test(BufReader::new(&self.buf));
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

The code above fails to compile, with the error message:

```
lifetimes.rs:17:31: 17:40 error: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for borrow expression due to conflicting requirements
lifetimes.rs:17         t.test(BufReader::new(&self.buf));
                                              ^~~~~~~~~
lifetimes.rs:16:5: 18:6 help: consider using an explicit lifetime parameter as shown: fn baz(&'a self, t: T)
lifetimes.rs:16     fn baz(&self, t: T) {
lifetimes.rs:17         t.test(BufReader::new(&self.buf));
lifetimes.rs:18     }
error: aborting due to previous error
```

However, if I add the named lifetime parameter, I cannot mutable borrow the `buf` field after calling `test`, as seen in `fn bar`. Commenting out the `fn baz` and trying to compile results in:

```
lifetimes.rs:13:22: 13:30 error: cannot borrow `self.buf` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
lifetimes.rs:13         let b = &mut self.buf;
                                     ^~~~~~~~
lifetimes.rs:12:32: 12:40 note: previous borrow of `self.buf` occurs here; the immutable borrow prevents subsequent moves or mutable borrows of `self.buf` until the borrow ends
lifetimes.rs:12         t.test(BufReader::new(&self.buf));
                                               ^~~~~~~~
lifetimes.rs:14:6: 14:6 note: previous borrow ends here
lifetimes.rs:11     fn bar(&'a mut self, t: T) {
lifetimes.rs:12         t.test(BufReader::new(&self.buf));
lifetimes.rs:13         let b = &mut self.buf;
lifetimes.rs:14     }
                    ^
error: aborting due to previous error
```

My understanding of this is that by adding the named lifetime `'a` to the `&'a mut self` parameter, the reference taken by `BufReader` has a lifetime as long as the `self` reference is valid, which is until the end of the function. This conflicts with the mutable borrow of `self.buf` on the line after.

However, I am not sure why I need the named lifetime parameter on the `self`. It seems to me that the `BufReader` reference should be able to only exist for the lifetime of the `t.test` method call. Is the compiler complaining because the `self.buf` borrow must be ensured to live only as long as the `&self` borrow? How would I go about doing that while still only borrowing it for the lifetime of the method call?

Any help in going about fixing this problem and understanding more about the semantics here would be much appreciated!

## Update

So I am still looking into this problem, and I have found [this test case](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/45cbdec4174778bf915f17561ef971c068a7fcbc/src/test/compile-fail/issue-13058.rs#L26) and [this issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/13058) that show basically what I am trying to do. I would very much like to understand why the error pointed to by the test case link is an error.

I can see in the issue rustc output that attempts to point out what the error is, but I am having trouble understanding what exactly it is trying to say.

Comment: Could you explain more about *why* you want to have `trait Bar<'a>` and what your goal is? In my case, I thought that it was a shorthand for putting `<'a>` on every method in the trait, but I was wrong. My current understanding is that you add a lifetime to the trait when the **implementer** needs to participate in the lifetime (perhaps because it is storing references with that lifetime).

Comment: What I am trying to do is use [bincode](https://github.com/TyOverby/bincode) to serialize structs/enums. Bincode defines a trait with a lifetime parameter, `DecoderReader<'a, R>`, which I am attempting to use. The problem comes because my struct has a type parameter on itself, and thus in the `impl` of my struct I have to specify that it is a `DecoderReader<'a, R>`. This is an example from the same project [here](https://github.com/crhino/IronSwarm/blob/master/src/swarm/socket.rs#L41).

Comment: That example above works, but the problem arises when I try to take another mutable reference of `self` in a function like the above. It errors out saying the I must wait for the previous mutable borrow to finish, which is at the end of the function.

Comment: "when I try to take another mutable reference" - If I understand you, that is your problem: You [simply aren't allowed to have two mutable references to the same thing at the same time](http://is.gd/0Z9chX). This is a *very* different question / problem.

Comment: Yes, that is why the compiler is failing. If look at my example code above, specifically `fn bar` and it's related rustc error (the second one), you will see that is what is happening. My thoughts are that the `&'a self` reference is keeping the `BufReader` alive for the length of `fn bar`, but what I want to do is only have that borrow alive for the length of the call to `test`.

Comment: FYI, [DecoderReader isn't a trait, it's a struct](https://github.com/TyOverby/bincode/blob/ae1a2996dcbf6df7f510da26fafd2485598b857b/src/reader.rs#L4-L6), so I'm not sure your example code is going to help with your real problem...

Comment: Ahh my bad, I meant that DecoderReader needs everything it serializes to be `Decodable`, which then means I have to specify in my `impl` something like `L:Decodable<DecoderReader<'e,BufReader<'e>>,IoError>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

I'm going to copy-edit my comment here:

I originally thought that adding a lifetime or generic parameter to the trait / struct / enum was a shorthand for putting it on every method in the trait, but I was **wrong**. My current understanding is that you add a lifetime to the trait / struct / enum when that item needs to participate in the lifetime, likely because it is storing a reference with that lifetime.

```rust
struct Keeper<'a> {
    counts: Vec<&'a i32>,
}

impl<'a> Keeper<'a> {
    fn add_one(&mut self, count: &'a i32) {
        if *count > 5 {
            self.counts.push(count);
        }
    }

    fn add_two<'b>(&mut self, count: &'b i32) -> i32 {
        *count + 1
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut cnt1 = 1;
    let mut cnt2 = 2;
    let mut k = Keeper { counts: Vec::new() };

    k.add_one(&cnt1);
    k.add_two(&cnt2);

    // cnt1 += 1; // Errors: cannot assign to `cnt1` because it is borrowed
    cnt2 += 1; // Just fine

    println!("{}, {}", cnt1, cnt2)
}
```

Here, we've added a lifetime to `Keeper` because it might store the reference it is given. The borrow checker *must assume* that the reference is stored for good when we call `add_one`, so once we call that method, we can no longer mutate the value.

`add_two`, on the other hand, creates a fresh lifetime that can only be applied to that function invocation, so the borrow checker *knows* that once the function returns, it is the One True Owner.

The upshot is, if you need to store a reference, then there's nothing you can do at this level. Rust can't make sure you are safe, and that's something it takes seriously.

However, I *bet you don't need to store the reference*. Move the `<'a, T: Bar<'a>>` from the `impl` to the `fn` and you'll be good to go.

Said another way: I bet you should never have `impl<A>` if your trait or struct don't **require** it. Put the generics on the methods instead.

**Original**

This compiles, but I'm not 100% sure it does what you intended:

```rust
impl Foo {
    fn baz<'a, T: Bar<'a>>(&'a self, t: T) {
        t.test(BufReader::new(&self.buf));
    }
}
```

[I fell into this trap myself](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/18549), so I'll paste what I was told:

> Everything in the impl block is parameterized. I've actually never
>   seen type parameters added to impl blocks themselves that aren't part
>   of the trait or type definition. It's far more common to parameterize
>   the individual methods that need it.

Perhaps other comments / answers can help explain in further detail.

Comment: This makes sense, I too had assumed as you had. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Removing all explicit lifetimes also works. I've found that I only add lifetimes when I'm sure I need them (i.e. to specifiy that two lifetimes should intersect at a given point which can't be known to the compiler).

I'm not sure exactly what you're going for, but this compiles (on rustc 0.13.0-nightly (cc19e3380 2014-12-20 20:00:36 +0000)).

```
use std::io::BufReader;
struct Foo {
    buf: [u8, ..10]
}

trait Bar {
    fn test(&self, arg: BufReader) {}
}

impl<T: Bar> Foo {
    fn bar(&mut self, t: T) {
        t.test(BufReader::new(&self.buf));
        let b = &mut self.buf;
    }

    fn baz(&self, t: T) {
        t.test(BufReader::new(&self.buf));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting. What is your use case for intersecting lifetimes? Does that syntax look like `'a: 'b + 'c`?

Comment: No it means two or more references with the same lifetime. I.e. when you need to specify that a particular reference's (such a function argument) lifetime is AT LEAST as long as another (say the functions return type). In reality their real lifetime's may be very different, but you only telling the compiler these two lifetimes have some sort of relationship.

Comment: While I think this is generally the right direction to go, it doesn't really answer the question: "when using a trait with an explicit lifetime" as it removes the explicit lifetime!